# Can't pick any document/image in react native (ANDROID 11)

Tags: react-native, android-permissions, android-11, react-native-image-picker

I cant pick any files from storage to app, upon picking it crashes the app
getting permission denied in logcat tho I have added these permissions in manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

```
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android 11 need add in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Docs: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en&visit_id=637596903669466448-3363514714&rd=1